# heroku router - - at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/favicon.ico

Tags: ruby, heroku, configuration, sinatra, rack

I received this error on heroku using Rack and Sinatra:

```
heroku router - - at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path=/favicon.ico
```

I fixed it by adding this line to my config.ru and adding a favicon.ico

```
map "/favicon.ico" do
    run Rack::File.new("./images/favicon.ico")
end
```

Is this solution acceptable, or is there a better way to handle this? It seemed a bit odd to me that this is treated as an error H13 "connection closed without response". I wouldn't have thought a favicon.ico would always be needed.